# Unable to retrieve URL for video in camera roll Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

Below is the code I have:

```
@IBAction func selectVideoButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let videoPicker = UIImagePickerController()
    videoPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.photoLibrary
    videoPicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String, kUTTypeMovie as String]
    videoPicker.delegate = self
    present(videoPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


func retrieveURL(_picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
    if let videoURL = info[.mediaURL] {
        print("Here is the URL: \(videoURL)")
        return
    }
}
```

I do not get any errors and the app does not crash after selecting a video, it just doesn't seem to do anything. Apologies if there is an answer for this somewhere, couldn't find it related to swift 5 or one that works.

I tried changing the "Any" to String and then amending the videoURL accordingly but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the correct delegate method

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    if let videoURL = info[.mediaURL] {
        print("Here is the URL: \(videoURL)") 
    }
    picker.dismiss(animated:true,completion:nil) // add this 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
   let videoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? URL
   print(videoURL)
   imagePickerController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```